# Space of measurable functions

Tags: functional-analysis, measure-theory

I've some trouble with the room $\mathfrak{L}^p(\Omega,\mathfrak{F},\mathbb{P})$ and $L^p(\Omega,\mathfrak{F},\mathbb{P})$.

I know as definition

$$\mathfrak{L}^p(\Omega,\mathfrak{F},\mathbb{P}):=\{f\,:\,\Omega\to\mathbb{R}\,|\,f\text{ is }\mathfrak{F}\text{-measurable and } ||f||_{L_p}:=\left(\int_{\Omega}|f(t)|^pd\mathbb{P}\right)^{\frac{1}{p}}<\infty\},$$

for any $1\leq p<\infty$. This is clear I think, but whats about $p=0,\infty$?

In the case of random variables, we can give this definition in a much easy way, as

$$\mathfrak{L}^p(\Omega,\mathfrak{F},\mathbb{P})=\{X\,|\,X\text{ is random variable and}\,\mathbb{E}[|X|^p]<\infty\}.$$

This is okay because the fact that $X$ is $\mathfrak{F}$-measurable is given by definition and the norm ist euqivalent to the expactation.

Maybe someone know a good paper which I can read to fill my knowlegde gabs? Thanks for helping and giving hints.

Comment: Almost every book about measure theory (or probability) contains a course about Lebesgue integration ... e.g. http://www.amazon.de/Measure-Integration-Theory-Sammlung-Guttentag/dp/3110167190 Moreover, the cases $p=0$, $0<p<1$ and $p=\infty$ are discussed in the article on wikipedia http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lp_space ...

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer! I have some books and there are this spaces discussed very shortly I think :(

Comment: I highly recommend http://terrytao.wordpress.com/2009/01/09/245b-notes-3-lp-spaces/

Comment: Let's also note that calling $X$ a real-valued random variable on $(\Omega, \Bbb{P})$ is equivalent to saying that $X : \Omega \to \Bbb{R}$ is a measurable function (random variable is just the  probabilists way to say measurable function). Moreover, the expected value of $X$, written $\Bbb{E}[X]$, is exactly the same as $\int_{\Omega} X \,d\Bbb{P}$. So, your two definitions are just symbol changes..